# Search Methods, Behavior and No Results

Tags: user-behavior, search, search-results

I've recently been working on a project where toner cartridges are being sold. The current product listing only lists the *manufacturer* and the *model number*, but excludes the *model name.*

For example, searching for "HP 9000" would yield a cartridge for that particular printer; however, searching for "HP LaserJet 9000" would yield nothing. (The printer is a LaserJet)

Now, my question is this: Would the return of no search results deter users who typed the *entire* model? -OR- On return of nothing, would the user simply type the manufacturer and the model number?

Could the experience be improved by displaying matches without the text "LaserJet" even when the manufacturer and number is a match?

Comment: Can't you just display the model name in the product listing? That is the best solution.

Comment: Yes, I know that's the solution... but I need proof that's a justified solution. I agree that's the answer to the problem.

Comment: In that case you should modify your question. Right now you are asking for alternate methods, what you want is backing for the claim that listing the model name is necessary.

Comment: That should do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your situation, a user will just copy the full model name from the printer properties dialog in Windows, to the search input field. So if it doesn't match, the user won't try to remove the model name and search again. Also, it might not be clear to him what exactly he should type into the search field.

I think it would be better to make a separate field for the manufacturer (radiogroup or checkbox list) and model (text field with autocomplete or combobox):

[image]

Comment: This is good stuff! Can you speak to the behavior if this weren't implemented? Aka: My situation before this solution.

Comment: I think that in your situation a user will just copy the full model name from printer properties dialog in Windows to the search input field. So if it doesn't match the user won't try to remove the model name and search again.

Comment: So, you would agree that the user would not search further if no results were yielded after the first unsuccessful search?

Comment: Yes, I do. Especially if it is not clean for him what exactly he should type to the search field.

Comment: Thanks so much! You should add that to the answer, just in case other users don't see the comments here.